# How to calculate the ship resistance caused by water viscosity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, drag, viscosity

If there is a ship going in the sea at 50km/h, and a length of 5m, width of 2m, how do I calculate the ship resistance caused by water viscosity? in other words I want to calculate the drag Force that should be made to overcome the water viscosity. I found this formula

> $F=\frac{1}{2} ρv^2A c_d$

but I can't calculate "$c_d$" (drag coefficient)

Comment: I tried to guess what you meant by the notation, you can correct it in any case. Also, it is always a good idea to specify what your symbols mean when stating an equation.

Comment: @JustMe - you need to specify the frontal cross-sectional area $A$ below the water line. For selection of the drag coefficient $C_d$ see: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drag-coefficient-d_627.html

Comment: Also note that the water viscosity doesn't enter the equation. So you can't claim the ship resistance is caused by the viscosity of the water.

Comment: [A Google search for *hull drag*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hull+drag) would be a good place to start doing some research for yourself. Ignore the links related to drag queens in Hull - they are unrelated to ships.